# Core Data Design: better 1 model with 2 stores or 2 models and 2 stores?

Tags: ios, macos, core-data, persistence

I'm facing a design problem using core data in an iOS app.
I've got two stores, one will contain a sort of catalog, the other only user data.
I've read all those questions:

- [CoreData with multiple stores: configuration woes](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/10224016/coredata-with-multiple-stores-configuration-woes)
- [Why might I want 2 or more Core Data models?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/10374796/why-might-i-want-2-or-more-core-data-models)
- [Can multiple (two) persistent stores be used with one object model, while maintaining relations from one to the other?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/5231775/can-multiple-two-persistent-stores-be-used-with-one-object-model-while-mainta)

But what I still didn't get is if it is better two use one model on two persistent stores or two models merge them at runtime with two stores. What will be easier, eventually, to migrate?

Comment: Why do you need 2 stores ? I always have all my data in 1 store.

Comment: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/10374796/why-might-i-want-2-or-more-core-data-models

Answer (score 2, accepted):

The definite way to go here is have **one** data model with **two** stores, administered via two so-called **configurations**.

In the model editor you can define which entities belong to which configuration.

In code you specify the identifier string of each configuration when adding the persistent store.

See the [WWDC 2012 video](https://developer.apple.com/videos/wwdc/2012/) on Core Data and iCloud that explains it really well.